# how to find files on directory based on filename pattern in python script

Tags: python, google-api, gspread

I have to modify my script to find the file that has a based on filename pattern, as of now it only export what specific filename that assigned on the script, can someone help me what I need to add or modify to my script?

**Scenario:**
I have file has date on its filename

MyProject_PO_20220516.csv

I still need to edit my script manually to exact filename everytime I want to import the csv file

**Solution that I need to modify to my script**

modify the script that can find the file with initial filename

Ex.

MyProject_PO + "_" + date + .csv

the initial filename is MyProject_PO_ , the script will find the file that met the pattern of filename on the script regardless what DATE that saved on it.

**My Script**

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import csv

SPREADSHEET_ID = 'SAMPLE_GSHEETDRIVE'
worksheet_name = 'CSVimport'
my_csv = 'MyProject_PO_20220516.csv'
credentials = 'key123.json'


def export_csv(my_csv, sheet_id):
    with open(my_csv, 'r', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as csv_file:
        csvContents = csv_file.read()
    body = {
        'requests': [{
            'pasteData': {
                "coordinate": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "rowIndex": "0",
                    "columnIndex": "0",
                },
                "data": csvContents,
                "type": 'PASTE_NORMAL',
                "delimiter": ',',
            }
        }]
    }
```

If you need more details let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I apply asterisk in python for more flexible filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72285161/how-can-i-apply-asterisk-in-python-for-more-flexible-filename)

Comment: trying to use glob but after inputing on my script I encountered this error, apologize I'm currently exploring the python.

  **File "ImportCSV.py", line 29, in export_csv
    with open(my_csv, 'r', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as csv_file:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list**

Comment: As the error mentions it, you give a list to the `open` function or you should give it a path or a string, may be try the first element of your list like `my_csv[0]` ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the input by the way I already found out what I need to make glob function works on my script.